# Initializing a String in Java

Tags: java, string

Is there any difference when we initialize a String by using:

> 1. java.lang.String
> 2. String (only)

Why do we write name of the complete package ?

Comment: You are not using `String` or `java.lang.String` to initialize anything.  You are simply using those tokens to **name** the type.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference. The `java.lang` package is imported implicitly in all java programs.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference if there is no custom "String" class defined.

If you, however, defined you own "String" class. Then you would need the extra java.lang in order to identify the correct String class.

Comment: hmmm i got it ! Thanks Gapton! :)

Answer (score 1):

> Why do we write name of the complete package ?

In this case, you shouldn't need to.

As @Asaph states, `java.lang` is *implicitly imported* into every class.  This means that your code can refer to `String` and other classes like `Boolean`, `System` and `NullPointerException` by their simple class names.

The only cases where you would *need* to refer to `String` by its fully qualified name (`java.lang.String`) are:

- if you are providing the class name as a String in some reflective API, or
- if you have stupidly written a class of your own whose simple name is `String`; e.g. `com.example.stupid.String`, and you have explicitly imported *that* version of `String` into some other class.

Best practice is to refer to classes in `java.lang` by their simple names, and NOT to define your own classes with the same simple name in other packages.

---

In the general case, these two forms mean exactly the same thing, and will give you exactly the same compiled code:

```
// version 1
package com.example.bar;
import com.example.foo.Foo;
public class Bar {
    private Foo myFool;
    ...
}

// version 2
package com.example.bar;
public class Bar {
    private com.example.foo.Foo myFool;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Lol. Gr8 post. Thank you so much Stephen C ! :)

Answer (score 0):

No difference

We write the package to distinguish it from a similarly named class, if any, in your project.  For instance if your project also has a class named `String`, java would not know which String class you want to use - yours or java's inbuilt one.

Comment: Thanks Raghuram! Your post was quite useful. :)